# Definition of intersection: Fulton vs Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S = k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated graded module over $S$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a homogeneous prime minimal over $\text{Ann}(M) =  \{s \in S| sM = 0 \}$. Hartshorne defines the multiplicity of $M$ along $\mathfrak p$ to be $\text{length}_{S_{\mathfrak p}} M_{\mathfrak p}$. But the way Fulton defines multiplicity of a irreducible component, it seems that the definition should be $\text{length}_{S_{(\mathfrak p)}} M_{(\mathfrak p )}$, where the later considers only elements of degree zero. Are the two equivalent?

[Also, in page 4 of https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/256B/notes/associated.pdf the definition of multiplicity seem to follow the later one.]

Comment: I have seen the above question. My question is different. Please don't judge content of a question by the title.